# how to disable table caption in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, captions, subcaption

I recieved tables in tex files and I included into my presentation. I cannot edit table file. How can I hide/disable caption from tables globally or during **\input**?

Some suggest the use of

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
```

but it does not work for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Madrid}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}

 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{float}

 \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}{•}
 \begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline 
 a & b & c \\ 
 \hline 
 a & b & c \\ 
 \hline 
 \end{tabular} 
 \caption{demo}
 \end{table}
 \end{frame}
 
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `caption` beamer template:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Madrid}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}

% \usepackage{caption}
 %\usepackage{float}

% \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setbeamertemplate{caption}{}}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{test}
 \begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline 
 a & b & c \\ 
 \hline 
 a & b & c \\ 
 \hline 
 \end{tabular} 
 \caption{demo}
 \end{table}
 \end{frame}
 
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works. But affect figures, too. Is there a way to apply only to tables?

Comment: @gvd see my updated answer

Comment: if subcaption package is present does not work.

Comment: @gvd ... then don't use the subcaption package? From the code in your question it seems that you are using unnumbered captions. There is no real advantage to use subcaption for them. You could just put your tables and images into columns besides each other.